# Llenar un select dentro de una ventana modal

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hola a todos espero esten bien, gente consulta: tengo un botón que me levanta una ventana modal, dentro del modal tengo que llenar un select con valores de una tabla, tengo una función para llenar el select, pero no logro incluir esta función dentro de evento que levanta la ventana... Dejo capturas del codigo a ver si me pueden dar una mano y ver que estoy haciendo mal:
La función "modal" es la que arma y levanta el modal:

```
   function modal(material_id){
            tecnico_id = $("#tecnico option:selected").val();
            //cargarSeries();
            var material_id = $('#materiales option:selected').val();
            var tecnico_id =$('#id_origen').val();
            var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
            var series =  cargarSeries;

            $("#modal-seriado #material_id").val(material_id);
            $("#modal-seriado #tecnico_id").val(tecnico_id);

            $("#modal-seriado #user_id").val(user_id);

            $("#modal-seriado #mac11").html(series);

            $('#modal-seriado').modal('show');
        }
```

la función "cargarSeries" es la que usaria para llenar el select con los datos...:

```
 function cargarSeries(tecnico_id){
        tecnico_id = $("#tecnico option:selected").val();
        $('#materiales').val('');
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('/devolucion/nuevos/series') }}"+`/${tecnico_id}`,
                method:"get",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(result){
                    console.log(result)
                    var opciones = '';
                    var opciones = '<option value="" disabled="disabled">--Series Asignadas--</option>';
                    result.data.forEach(element => {
                    opciones += `<option value="${element.material_id}" data-seriado="${element.seriado}" data-cantidad="${element.cantidad}">${element.nombre_producto}</option>`;
                     });

                    $("#mac11").html(opciones);
                    }
            });
    }
```

Pero al ejecutar el script me muestra el mensaje en consola:
[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos a todos y gracias desde ya

Comment: El código en texto por favor, de lo contrario no te podemos ayudar.

Comment: Nicolas la función cargarSeries no tiene sentido que le pases por parametro un **tecnico_id**, cuando después esta variable la obtienes del **$("#tecnico option:selected").val()**. La función **modal** te pasa lo mismo, le pasas un parámetro que luego obtienes de un select y luego vuelves a obtenerlo **material_id**. Organiza un poco ese código, y en CargarSeries deja un `alert('hola');` y cuando veas el hola empieza a rellenar las funciones poco a poco.